# Generic type for a struct

Tags: c++, qt

Given the following two methods:

```
QVector<QPointF> DataProvider::getPointsSize()
{
  QVector<QPointF> points;
  foreach (Database::TbRawInItem item, rawInData)
    points << QPointF(item.timestamp.toTime_t(), item.data.size());
  return points;
}

QVector<QPointF> DataProvider::getPointsPacketCounter()
{
  QVector<QPointF> points;
  foreach (Database::BeaconItem item, beaconData)
    points << QPointF(item.timestamp.toTime_t(), item.packetCounter);
  return points;
}
```

I would like to improve it to a `getPoints` method which would be called passing the foeach arguments. Something like this:

```
getPoints(TbRawInItem, rawInData);
getPoints(BeaconItem, beaconData);
```

Class members `rawInData` and `beaconData` are defined as:

```
QVector<Database::TbRawInItem> rawInData;
QVector<Database::BeaconItem> beaconData;
```

And `item` is a struct:

```
struct TbRawInItem {
  unsigned int id;
  QDateTime timestamp;
  QByteArray data;
  char interface;
};
struct BeaconItem {
  QDateTime timestamp;
  unsigned int packetCounter;
  unsigned int cmdRxCounter;
  unsigned int cmdValidCounter;
  double battVoltage;
  double totalSysCurrent;
  double battTemperature;
  double photoVoltaicVoltage1;
  double photoVoltaicVoltage2;
  double photoVoltaicVoltage3;
  double photoCurrent;
};
```

My question is how to deal with the `item` struct?

Comment: if I understand correctly: you want one function instead of the first 2?

Comment: yes @bolov, that's what I want.

Comment: the obvious answer would be to use a templated method, but in this case it would be too complicated because you need to call `item.data.size()` or `item.packetCounter` depending on the type of `item`. For 4 lines of code in each function it is just not worth it.

Comment: The thing is there are many more objects like rawInData and beaconData. So, for each of this objects a specific getPointsXXX is necessary. Would you mind provide a minimum intro on how to use a templated method?

Comment: k i'll cook an answer

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned int getSize(Database::TbRawInItem const &item) {
  return item.data.size();
}

unsigned int getSize(Database::BeaconItem const &item) {
  return item.packetCounter;
}
// you need to create an overload for each type of item
// If you have many item types and some of them get the size the same way
// you can group them together (just one function for all) with
// templates and SFINAE
// That is an advanced tehnique though.

template <class T>
QVector<QPointF> DataProvider::getPoints(T const &data) {
  QVector<QPointF> points;
  foreach (T item, data)
    points << QPointF(item.timestamp.toTime_t(), getSize(data));
  return points;
}

getPoints(rawData); // T will be deduced as Database::TbRawInItem
getPoints(beaconData); // T will be deduced as Database::BeaconItem
```

or with lambdas:

```
template <class T, class Func>
QVector<QPointF> DataProvider::getPoints(T const &data, Func const &get_size)    {
  QVector<QPointF> points;
  foreach (T item, data)
    points << QPointF(item.timestamp.toTime_t(), get_size(data));
  return points;
}

getPoints(rawData, [](Database::TbRawInItem const &item) {
    return item.data.size();}));
getPoints(beaconData, [](Database::BeaconItem const &item) {
    return item.packetCounter;}));
```

or something in between

---

*Disclaimer*:

- I am not familiar with `foreach` I suppose it is a `qt` thing. Nevertheless the concept it is the same.
- I haven't compiled it since I don't have a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so there might be syntax errors.

Comment: if you are unfamiliar with templates or lambdas this might seem alien, but it is not difficult. It falls out of the scope of this question to make a template and a lambda tutorial. You can search the web for simple tutorials. For the 1st example you need only templates.

Comment: realized that `getSize()` doesn't have to be templated, just a plain c++ overloaded function, so the example is simpler now.

Comment: Please let me know if it helps. Let me know if you get compilation errors, as I stated I didn't compiled it so I might have made some syntax mistakes.

Comment: It helps very much @bolov. As you stated both seemed alien :), but I think I got the idea of templates. Still haven't studied lambdas.

Comment: Unfurtunately it's not possible to assume directly the return statement of the getSize. For BeaconItem there are multiple returns, each struct member should be returned, i.e. packetCounter. But you have provided the tools, thank you. Now I think the case needs a little more reasoning from my side.